# What does the explicit formula means in this sentence?

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm reading Classic and Multilinear Harmonic analysis vol.2 - Muscalu, Schlag

In page 134, it says,

$$\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}-F(y-x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(y)d\sigma(y)=0$$

can be shown by using explicit formula for F, where F is the fundamental solution for Laplacian in the complex plane given by

$$F(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|$$

So in here what does it mean by explicit formula? And how can I derive that the show that the above equation is true?

Here $B(x,\epsilon)$ is in bounded Lipschitz domain $U$.

Comment: The integral is not zero, but the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$. In $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$ you have $-F(y-x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log \epsilon$. Hence if $u$ is smooth enough, say $C^1$, you get the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that $\epsilon$ goes to zero.. thanks!